# How to define local variable in another react file

Tags: reactjs, typescript, scope, react-hooks

I have to use Abc variable from a.tsx to another b.tsx file. How can I access that Abc variable in another .tsx file?

Current a.tsx:

```
export const ProfilePicEditor = (props: ProfilePicEditorProps) => {
    const [Abc, setAbc] = useState(
        'some string'
    )
```

I tried doing 'export {Abc}' in my a.tsx file and importing it into b.tsx file as 'Import {Abc} from 'a.tsx'. But it didn't worked out. Any possible reasons?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data between two sibling React.js components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34734301/passing-data-between-two-sibling-react-js-components)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to create a custom react hook, maybe take a look at this article. It has a pretty good working example, and good steps for extracting one: https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-hooks-fetch-data/

Comment: I'm able to work with hooks in same file but when I try using import function in b.tsx it gives me an error cannot find name Abc or Abc does not exist on ProfilePicEditor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the variable as a prop to the child component, if the parent is who wants to accede to the variable you can use a ref

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ChildComponent = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <ChildComponent ref={this.ChildComponent} />;
  }
}
```

you can use it like this:

const currentChildComponent = this.currentChildComponent.current;

Answer (score 0):

What is the relationship between the two components? Parent/child? Siblings?

React generally expects you (and is designed) to pass data as part of the state via the props.

So if you want to pass data between components and you are not using Redux or a similar library, you need to pass the data in the constructor as a prop and have your constructor extract it.

Comment: The relationship between the two components is Parent/Child

Comment: Then you can use a callback in the parent to pass the data back from the child. Create a function on the parent that takes the data as a parameter and invoke it from the child. 

There's an example here: https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17